# How use function body onload in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have this code

http://www.thediscopalace.com/testing.php

If you see `<body onload="start()" onresize="resize()" onorientationchange="resize()">`. I want this code working like this

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("body").onload = start; or window.onload = start;
});
```

So just working only if i click **button**. But why that code not working?

Comment: Does not make sense to me. `onload` is triggered when the body loads.
why should you put that on a button?

What do you want to do actually?

Comment: Um, the page has already loaded so binding load on a click makes no sense. There is also no `$().onload` in jQuery.

Comment: i want remove onload from body. only like this `<body onresize="resize()" onorientationchange="resize()">`

Comment: The jQuery equivalent of `element.onload = function` is `$(selector).load(function)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you could make something like that:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  start();
  $(window).on("resize orientationchange", resize)
});
```

Comment: You can combine the 3rd and 4th line: `$(window).on("resize orientationchange", resize)`

Comment: sory last question, can i use fadeIn if start function for animation when show?